# Swift iOS TableView cell items disappears when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I scroll through my tableview I see that some badges in my list disappears.

My cell is set to have a custom class of `CustomTableViewCell`

**CustomTableViewCell**:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var badgeIcon: AsyncImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!

    func configureCell(data: JSON) {

        if let itemType = data["item_type"].int, itemTitle = data["item_type"].string {

          title.text = itemTitle

          if itemType == 1 {
             badgeIcon.hidden = true
          } else {
             badgeIcon.hidden = false
          }
        }
```

**tableview**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCustomCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

        let data = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(data)

        //Dont show highlight
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

        return cell

    }
```

When my tableView first loads everything is displayed right with **badgeIcon** being shown/hidden where it should be, but if I scroll up/down a few times the **badgeIcon** will always remain hidden

Comment: Try to add badge inside your custom cell class, send to class only itemtype. cell.itemType = 1, by default leave it false.

Comment: You should add a default behavior for your badge, for example badgeIcon.hidden = false before if let itemType =..

Comment: Where do you call `configureCell`?  Can you show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function?

Comment: By default, is your badgeIcon initialized to hidden = true? That could be an issue. Are you able to confirm it's entering the if let statement every time you reuse these cells with print statements?

Comment: This has to do with the dequeuereusableCell function. Could you please post that code here so I can tell you what's wrong and update my answer with something useful.

Comment: @Shen updated my question.

Comment: @Coder1000 updated my question

Comment: @AlexKosyakov I had it set hidden = false in storyboard. But when I also added it before the let.. as you said it worked!

Comment: @user2722667 glad it helped man)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your `UITableViewCell` subclass, override prepareForReuse with:

```
badgeIcon.hidden = true
```

This way you can use a "clean slate" when configuring your cells upon reuse.

Comment: Thanks, but when I added `badgeIcon.hidden = true` before the `if let..` it also worked